# Richtiges Wort für Vorderräder, Position zum Abbiegen

Tags: single-word-request

[image]

Wie würdet ihr die Lage der Vorderräder dieses Wagens beschreiben? Keins der Wörter, die mir einfallen, passt: *verdreht, verstellt...*?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Die Vorderräder sind eingeschlagen.

Comment: Besser die Vorderräder sind eingeschlagen als die Scheiben :-)

Comment: @Hubert haha! Sonst, gute Antwort - auf den Punkt gebracht.